# Oddities with postgres SQL [negative date interval and alias that doesn't work only in condition clause]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm coming to you guys with with two small oddities I can't seem to understand with postgres:

(1)

```
  SELECT "LASTREQUESTED", 
         (DATE_TRUNC('seconds', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - "LASTREQUESTED") 
              - INTERVAL '8 hours') AS "TIME"
    FROM "USER" AS u 
    JOIN "REQUESTLOG" AS r ON u."ID" = r."ID" 
ORDER BY "TIME"
```

[image: result]

I'm calculating when users can make their next request [once every 8 hours], but if you look at entry 16 I get "1 day -06:20:47" instead of "18:00:00" ish, unlike every other line. [The table LASTREQUESTED is a simple timestamp, nothing different here from the other entries for line 16], why is that?

(2)

On the same request, if I try to add a condition on the "TIME" column, the compiler says it doesn't exist although using it to order by is ok. I don't get why.

```
   SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('seconds', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - "LASTREQUESTED") 
               - INTERVAL '8 hours') AS "TIME" 
     FROM "USER" AS u 
     JOIN "REQUESTLOG" AS r ON u."ID" = r."ID" 
    WHERE "TIME" > 0 
 ORDER BY "TIME";
```

Comment: 2 different questions should go in 2 different questions posts, I think.

Comment: Question #2 appears to be a duplicate of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3241352/3004881).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Question #1: negative hours but positive days?

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT), this is a situation where PostgreSQL differs from the SQL standard:

> According to the SQL standard all fields of an interval value must have the same sign…. PostgreSQL allows the fields to have different signs….
>
> Internally interval values are stored as months, days, and seconds. This is done because the number of days in a month varies, and a day can have 23 or 25 hours if a daylight savings time adjustment is involved. The months and days fields are integers while the seconds field can store fractions. …

You can see a more extreme example of this with the following query:

```
=# select interval '1 day' - interval '300 hours';
     ?column?     
------------------
 1 day -300:00:00
(1 row)
```

So this is not a single interval in seconds expressed in a strange way; instead, it's an interval of 0 months, +1 day, and -1,080,000.0 seconds. If you are certain that there's no daylight savings time issues with the timestamps that you got these intervals from, you can use [`justify_hours`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) to convert days into 24-hour periods and get an interval that makes more sense:

```
=# select justify_hours(interval '1 day' - interval '300 hours');
   justify_hours    
--------------------
 -11 days -12:00:00
```

## Question #2: `SELECT` columns can't be used in `WHERE`?

This is standard PostgreSQL behavior. See [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3241352/3004881). Solutions presented there include:

- Repeat the expression twice, once in the `SELECT` list, and again in the `WHERE` clause. (I've done this more times than I want to remember…)

  ```
  SELECT (my - big * expression) AS x
  FROM stuff
  WHERE (my - big * expression) > 5
  ORDER BY x
  ```
- Create a subquery without that `WHERE` filter, and put the `WHERE` conditions in the outer query

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT (my - big * expression) AS x
        FROM stuff) AS subquery
  WHERE x > 5
  ORDER BY x
  ```
- Use a `WITH` statement to achieve something similar to the subquery trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very insightful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't now exactly why it's calculating as-is (maybe because you subtract an Interval from another Interval) but when you change the calculation to Timestamp minus Timestamp it works as expected:

```
DATE_TRUNC('seconds', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (LASTREQUESTED + INTERVAL '8 hours'))
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/44484/1)

Regarding #2: Based on Standard SQL the columns in the Select-list are calculated after FROM/WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING, but before ORDER, that's why you can't use an alias in WHERE. There are some [good articles on that topic](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you) written by Itzik Ben-Gan (based on MS SQL Server, but similar for PostgreSQL).