# Limit query by sum of attributes of objects in Rails and Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Lead model that has a pre-calculated float column called "sms_price". I want to allow users to send text messages to those leads, and to assign a budget to their campaigns (something similar to what you can find on fb ads).

I need a scope that can limit the number of leads by the total price of those leads. So for example if the user has defined a total budget of 200

- id: 1  | sms_price: 0.5 | total_price: 0.5
- id: 2  | sms_price: 1.2 | total_price: 1.7
- id: 3  | sms_price: 0.9 | total_price: 2.6
- ...
- id: 94 | sms_price: 0.8 | total_price: 199.4 <--- stop query here
- id: 95 | sms_price: 0.7 | total_price: 200.1

So I need two things in my scope:

1. Calculate the total price recursively
2. Get only the leads that have a total price lower than the desired budget

So far I have only managed to do the first task (*Calculate the total price recursively*) using this scope:

```
scope :limit_by_total_price, ->{select('"leads".*, sum(sms_price) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS total_price')}
```

This works and if I do `Lead.limit_by_total_price.last.total_price` I get `38039.7499999615`

Now what I need is a way to retrieve only the leads that have a total price lower than the budget:

```
scope :limit_by_total_price, ->(budget){select('"leads".*, sum(sms_price) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS total_price').where('total_price < ?', budget)}
```

But it doesn't recognise the total_price attribute:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "total_price" does not exist
```

Why does it recognise the total_price attribute in a single object and not in the scope ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241352/using-an-alias-column-in-the-where-clause-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the columns calculated in a SELECT clause are not available to the WHERE clause in the same statement. To do what you want, you need a subquery.

You can do this and yet stay in the Rails universe using ActiveRecord's [`from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from) method. The technique is nicely illustrated in [this Hashrocket blog post](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/advanced-queries-with-activerecord-s-from-method).

In your case it might look something like this (because of the complexity, I would use a class method rather than a scope):

```
def self.limit_by_total_price(budget)
  subquery = select('leads.*, sum(leads.sms_price) over(order by leads.id) as total_price')
  from(subquery, :leads).where('total_price < ?', budget)
end
```